# fail2ban inside official MariaDB docker image

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, fail2ban

I am running a docker image `mariadb:10.9.2-jammy`

I noticed with that I get a lot of brute force logging attempts cluttering my logs when I do `docker logs mariadb`

Is it possible to implement something like `fail2ban` inside my image ? I know it works for ssh connections but I am not sure if it would work for mysql connections too ?

Comment: Do you *really* need MariaDB to be publicly accessible? Normally it's restricted to same machine or a small set of other machines. Running it over the open Internet is kinda hazardous...

Comment: @vidarlo yes I need for administration with special unique account but Root access is only enabled on localhost and my app connects with LAN.

Comment: If it's for administration, a ssh tunnel must be possible? `ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 user@example.org`?

Comment: @vidarlo this is what Im doing already; humm... Maybe Im missing something and need somehow to disconnect it completely from the web ? Not sure how; I just have my port 3306:3306 exposed in my docker compose

Comment: You should *not* expose mysql to the internet.

Comment: If using compose, you don't need to expose as those on the same network are visible. This can include a sshd container, with an expose and authorized keys only, for your port forwarding.